# Testing multiple REST endpoints for spring-boot application

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot, h2, in-memory-database

I'm some what new to spring boot but have extensive spring experience. Basically I have 2 REST endpoint and want to have 2 test classes to test each of them. I am using an embedded H2 db with the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceDatabasePopulator populator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator pop = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        pop.addScript(new ClassPathResource("db/migration/V1_0001__create_queue_server_table.sql"));
        pop.addScript(new ClassPathResource("db/migration/V1_0002__queue_server_entries.sql"));
        pop.addScript(new ClassPathResource("db/migration/V1_0005_update_server_table_creation.sql"));
        pop.addScript(new ClassPathResource("sql/update-server-values.sql"));
        pop.setContinueOnError(true);

        return pop;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dbInit(DataSource ds, ResourceDatabasePopulator populator) {
        DataSourceInitializer init = new DataSourceInitializer();
        init.setDataSource(ds);
        init.setDatabasePopulator(populator);
        init.setEnabled(true);

        return init;
    }
}
```

My test files:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {VitelQueueServiceApplication.class, TestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
public class RestEndpointTests {

    private static final int EXPECTED_SERVER_COUNT = 10;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webCtx;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webCtx).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void successListAll() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/listall")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(EXPECTED_SERVER_COUNT)));
    }
```

Test case 2:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {VitelQueueServiceApplication.class, TestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
public class UpdateServerTest {
    private static final boolean VALID_VALUES_ACTIVE = true;
    private static final String VALID_VALUES_UPDATE_LOCATION = "/home/ftp/in";
    private static final String VALID_VALUES_ALT_UPDATE_LOCATION = "/opt/ftp/in";

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webCtx;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webCtx).build();
    }
    @Test
    public void validVitelServerName() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/updateserver/find/cptlext03"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.active", equalTo(VALID_VALUES_ACTIVE)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.updateLocation", equalTo(VALID_VALUES_UPDATE_LOCATION)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.alternativeUpdateLocation", equalTo(VALID_VALUES_ALT_UPDATE_LOCATION)));
    }

    @Test
    public void invalidVitelServerName() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/updateserver/find/blah"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(content().json("{}"));
    }
}
```

The issue I am seeing is that the 2'nd test never finds any data. I've tried using @DirtiesContext to force a reload after each test method but that has not yielded the result I was hoping for.

I'm leery about this test case file become extremely large as more endpoints are added.